# Why do they develop this DIY Lucy device and not use something available?

Tags: film-techniques, castle

Since season 8, Richard owns a new gadget: Lucy. A small pyramid on the desk at the kitchen, glowing blue and talking with the voice of Aubrey Plaza.

Why do they develop things like this, when they hold a iPhone with Siri on it in their hands?

Comment: In Germany, for example, there is a limitation for product placement, maybe this is reached?

Answer (score 3):

Licensing a known property such as Apple's Siri is a time-consuming and potentially expensive proposition for any show. The fact that you then want it to **exclusively do things that Siri can't do** (operating and running a smart household, acting as a counsellor for Castle, interrupting would-be murderers) makes that doubly difficult.

Siri is basically a glorified search app, not a home OS and lacks any of the sophistication shown by Lucy. On top of that, having Siri as his home manager means that you don't get to cast a popular actress like Audrey Plaza into the role.

Comment: In "the big bang Theory" they have implemented all. Siri has its own voice and gives Raj individual (non Apple) answers!

Comment: This "Lucy" is much more akin to Samantha in the movie *Her* than to Siri anyway. It plays into the characterization that Castle is super rich and gets all the "cool new toys"

Comment: @J.Doe - It may interest you to know that Siri (the app) proved far too limited for the show's needs (quality of voice too low, responses too unpredictable and slow) so they [hired the voice actress who voiced Siri to play the part](http://articles.latimes.com/2013/oct/19/entertainment/la-et-st-conversation-siri-susan-bennett-20131020)

Comment: @Richard: this I mean why they place in the big bang Theory the iPhone on video track and use a custom voice on the sound track

Comment: The home automation device made by Amazon called "Echo" is probably the closest analogous device. It uses the Alexa voice recognition system (similar to Siri) to answer basic questions.

Comment: @J.Doe - Why pay the license if you're going to completely reinvent it? Flip that, if you're Apple why would you pay money for someone to highlight how crappy your operating system is?